# On click on li scroll it on the top of container

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've an `UL` with `overflow:auto` and fixed height. In this `UL` I've some `LI`.

I want to create a function where on click on `LI` it will place at the top of the `UL`.

```
<ul class=list>
 <li>A</li>
 <li>B</li>
 <li>C</li>
 <li>D</li>
 <li>E</li>
</ul>
```

Example, if I click on D it should move to the top.

https://codepen.io/andrew_88/pen/mYWdmg

Comment: `<li onClick="document.getElementById('list').scrollTop = 0;">A</li>`

Comment: You could use the [`scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) attribute.

Comment: @Andrew you need to clear up exactly what it is you want.  I reworded the question to "move it to the top" as that was the only sensible meaning of "must be on the top" - you need to review edits to your question; if they don't match the question then you need to undo and *provide better feedback*.  In this case we've *interpreted* this as "move to the top" - ie move it.  If you mean it should *scroll* to the top, then this makes no sense as it would already be visible in order for it to be clicked on.  Please provide *clear* before and after requirements.

Comment: There was also an edit that *completely* changed the question to make it very much  re-order the `li`.  I've rolled-back that change based on your comment that you don't want to re-order.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.prependTo` to move the `li` to the top:

```
$('li').on('click', function() {
  $(this).prependTo($(this).closest("ul"));
  $('.list').animate({scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);
})
```

Updated codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LoWYMq?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
$('li').on('click', function() {
  $(this).prependTo($(this).parent())
  $(this).parent().animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  })
})
```

I've also updated the pen [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/joBOXB)

Comment: no. I don't want to change the order of li

Comment: then what do you want exactly?